# Select one number between others with spaces

Tags: php, regex

Can I select the number 3433 in this example of generated file with so many spaces that I can not control?

```
BIOLOGIQUES                                                             3433     130906 / 3842
```

Please see the example here : http://regexr.com?368ku

The number 3343 could change from one file to an other, but it will have always the same position/

I'm using regex with php.

It's a pdf document that I transform with pdftotext function of xpdf and so I must have that number which change from a pdf to an other.

It's very bad positioned and I don't know how to capture it via regex.

I tried:

```
BIOLOGIQUES [^0-9]*\K([0-9]*)(.*)
```

http://regexr.com?368ku
but it takes all the numbers, 
I need only the first one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are making this far too complicated. Something like this will work:

```
BIOLOGIQUES\s+(\d+)
```

Which matches the string "BIOLOGIQUES" literally, then one or more whitespace characters, then captures one or more digits, saving your number in capturing group 1.

Use it in PHP like this:

```
$str = 'DES ANALYSES BIOLOGIQUES                                                                                        3433     130906 / 3842';
preg_match( '/BIOLOGIQUES\s+(\d+)/', $str, $matches);
echo $matches[1];
```

You can see from [this demo](http://3v4l.org/BGBd2) that this produces:

```
3433
```

Comment: Thank you 

It took the word BIOLOGIQUE whith it and the series of spaces 

I tried BIOLOGIQUES[^0-9]*\K([0-9]*)() and worked fine
What do you think about that syntax?

Comment: @amorino - It will match many things you're not expecting. You have a blank capturing group `()`, and the `[^0-9]` causes you to match things *other* then whitespace, which is not what you're trying to do. See my answer, I think it is much more straightforward than your approach.

Comment: Hello,
What if I would capture 3842 ?
Thank you

Comment: Hello, I have only one group please see here : http://www.rubular.com/r/ongIv3gLmx
I want to select the last numbers 3842

Comment: @amorino - Something like `BIOLOGIQUES\s+(\d+)\s+\d+\s+\/\s+(\d+)` should work. See http://www.rubular.com/r/Jv6QRYSWFP

Answer (score 0):

I tried `BIOLOGIQUES[^0-9]*\K([0-9]*)()` and worked fine